# JS fails to download in IE 8 only

Tags: internet-explorer-8

IE 8 on Windows 7 is failing to download a JS file, IE 9, Firefox and Chrome are unaffected.

It can be replicated on several PCs using IE 8. I have checked permissions on the IIS hosting the site.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

---

Its one particular file *.js

Ive loaded it onto another server and its OK, so i ruled out any syntax issues with the file and ruled out IE 8 as its loading OK.

I believe  its more to do with the IIS configuration.

Comment: How is it "failing" to do so?

Comment: The download dialog box opens and error box infront stating, "Unable to download "filesname.js" from "server" It seems as if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved, we removed the pragma  value: no-cache in the http headers section of IIS

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening with a particular file? That is, is it loading other JS files ok? I had a similar problem, turned out to be a syntax error in the javascript which was causing IE to silently ignore the file.

Comment: So other js files are being served up ok from the server?

Comment: Other js files are  also failing in IE 8, but not in Chrome or Firefox. It does IIS related as opposed to browser.

Comment: Was the other server in the same domain as problem server? If not, was either of them local, i.e. compared to the clients?

Comment: The others servers are in the same domain hosted by Amazon, just different host names, same version of IIS running.

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if the request is getting to IIS? What is the IIS version, e.g. are they running urlscan?